# tikzcd and aligned, how to?

Tags: align, tikz-cd

I have a problem when trying to make `tikzcd` and `aligned` environment coexist.
In particular, when nesting an `aligned` inside a `tikzcd`, the alignment is completely wrong and pushed randomly to the right of the cell(s).

For example, in the following output the first part is done with an `aligned` inside a `tikzcd`, and second with the same `aligned` inside an `align*`.

[image]

This is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows, cd, patterns}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}[baseline=(current  bounding  box.center), cramped, row sep = 0ex,
    column sep = 1.5em,
        /tikz/column 1/.append style={anchor=base east},
        /tikz/column 2/.append style={anchor=base west}]
        A\rar &B\\
        x \rar[mapsto] & \left\{\begin{aligned}
            &f(x), && \text{ if } x\in X \text{ and some other condition},\\
            &g(x), && \text{ otherwise.}
            \end{aligned}\right.
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
    \begin{align*}
    A &\longrightarrow B\\
    x & \longmapsto \left\{\begin{aligned}
            &f(x), && \text{ if } x\in X \text{ and some other condition},\\
            &g(x), && \text{ otherwise.}
            \end{aligned}\right.
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how to obtain the correct behaviour of `aligned` when nested in `tikzcd`?

Comment: What's the reason for `tikzcd`?

Comment: I should use these things inside some more complicated commutative diagrams, and I like the way `tikzcd` renders them and makes easier typesetting complicated ones (the code in the question is just an example).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a `tikzcd` environment, `&` has a different meaning than usual. Use `ampersand replacement` to keep the original one.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
  baseline=(current  bounding  box.center),
  cramped,
  row sep = 0ex,
  column sep = 1.5em,
  /tikz/column 1/.append style={anchor=base east},
  /tikz/column 2/.append style={anchor=base west},
  ampersand replacement=\&,
]
A\arrow[r] \& B\\
x \arrow[r,mapsto] \&
  \left\{\begin{aligned}
  &f(x), && \text{ if } x\in X \text{ and some other condition},\\
  &g(x), && \text{ otherwise.}
  \end{aligned}\right.
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\begin{align*}
A &\longrightarrow B\\
x & \longmapsto
  \left\{\begin{aligned}
  &f(x), && \text{ if } x\in X \text{ and some other condition},\\
  &g(x), && \text{ otherwise.}
  \end{aligned}\right.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd prefer the more consistent `\arrow` style, than using `\rar` and similar commands.

You might want to use `cases`, though:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
  baseline=(current  bounding  box.center),
  cramped,
  row sep = 0ex,
  column sep = 1.5em,
  /tikz/column 1/.append style={anchor=base east},
  /tikz/column 2/.append style={anchor=base west},
  ampersand replacement=\&,
]
A\arrow[r] \& B\\
x \arrow[r,mapsto] \&
  \left\{\begin{cases}
  f(x), & \text{if $x\in X$ and some other condition},\\
  g(x), & \text{otherwise.}
  \end{cases}\right.
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternative approach: define a `cdaligned` environment where `&` has the default meaning. However, all “inner” environments would need the same approach.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newenvironment{cdaligned}{\catcode`\&=4 \aligned}{\endaligned}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
  baseline=(current  bounding  box.center),
  cramped,
  row sep = 0ex,
  column sep = 1.5em,
  /tikz/column 1/.append style={anchor=base east},
  /tikz/column 2/.append style={anchor=base west},
]
A\arrow[r] & B\\
x \arrow[r,mapsto] &
  \left\{\begin{cdaligned}
  &f(x), && \text{ if } x\in X \text{ and some other condition},\\
  &g(x), && \text{ otherwise.}
  \end{cdaligned}\right.
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Precise and correct, like always! Thank you soooo very much, again and again, for sharing your expertise! :)