# Cannot use tikz-cd in align-environment

Tags: align, tikz-cd

Why, as in the following MWE, does `tikz-cd` give me errors inside `align`-environment? Is there a way that the ampersand for `tikz-cd` is ignored by align?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{tikzcd} 
A
      \arrow{r}{f}
     & B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Is my only alternative to use `equation` instead?

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/639747/ https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324788/

Comment: oh thanks, and sorry, it was answered there (not shown as suggestion when I typed the question)

Comment: No worries :) I found them through google ..

Comment: You may want to use `ampersand replacement=\&` as tikzcd option (and replace & by \&) or `equation` environment.